# Chrome Bug!? - infinite scrolling above page body (several Pages)

Tags: google-chrome, scroll, overflow, chromium, overscroll

[image]

I recognized this Bug on several Pages occurring in Chromium related browsers. I opened up a [Chromium Issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1220091), where the project members could not reproduce the problem - I am trying to figure out why this is happening (since the Problem occurs on Pages as like google.com, amazon.com, and so on, on several Mac-OS devices, which have nothing else in common) - we tried it on a clean Chrome installation, where The Problem is also occurring. To me it seems to be a bug - now I'd like to know if other people are also not able to reproduce. If you can reproduce (to reproduce read the following lines below) and/or find something new/interesting about the problem consider supporting the [Ticket/Chromium Issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1220091).

#### Chrome Version

91.0.4472.101 (Offizieller Build) (x86_64)

#### URLs tested

- https://www.google.de/
- https://www.microsoft.com/de-de
- https://www.amazon.de/

#### Other browsers tested

- Safari: hasn't the problem
- Firefox: hasn't the problem
- Edge: has the same issue (also Chromium based)
- Chrome Canary: has the same issue (also Chromium based)

#### How to reproduce the problem?

Refresh Page (Command+Shift+R) and Scroll upwards while page is loading or in parallel (you have to be quick to reproduce).

#### What is the expected result?

Expectedly the Page should not over-scroll and stop at the pages top/end instead the page can be scrolled infinite above the pages top, same issue appears by scrolling down, where scrolling should stop at the bottom of the page.

#### What happens instead?

Browser keeps scrolling above the pages top/bottom infinitively. Once triggered the infinite scrolling wont disappear, even after refreshing the page - the only way to change the behavior is to copy the url and paste it within a new tab.

Comment: May be related to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56805739/css-scroll-snaps-overflows-body-when-reaching-top

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Small update**: it seems like the problem appears when using a logitech mx master mouse (if you run into the problem when not using this specific model, let the chrome people know) - it looks like it can be solved by following steps:

1. Open a terminal window.
2. Type in the following command then hit enter:
   defaults write -g NSScrollViewRubberbanding -bool false

Source: https://www.computerworld.com/article/2726533/turn-off-elastic-scrolling-in-os-x.html

Hopefully they'll fix the problem in chrome itself, until then this should solve the problem.

Comment: I had this issue with a MX Anywhere 2 and MX Master 3 indeed.

Comment: Same here. Thanks for the solution

Comment: Here's a similar link to the one posted in this answer, but with a bit more context/explanation about the issue: https://www.cnet.com/tech/computing/disable-elastic-scrolling-in-os-x/

Comment: Here's a similar answer on SuperUser: https://superuser.com/questions/1088396/chrome-disable-mouse-wheel-elastic-scroll-at-end-of-webpages with additional context as well

Answer (score 3):

**Update: See Irgend Son Hansel answer**

I don't think there's an official fix currently, but what I do when this bug comes up is to simply click the scroll bar. It usually fixes it for a while before it comes back up again.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what the OP is asking but I assume they are looking for a fix or a workaround for this?

I *occasionally* experience the same on my MacOS machine. For me, refreshing page does not work. What I do is the following:

- copy url of the current page
- open new tab and navigate to the same url
- close old tab

Comment: The issue still isn't fixed - best thing to do would be to provide the chromium team, within the related threat, to provide further information: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1220091

Comment: If I had a reliable way to replicate the issue, I would do it but it happens so randomly I don't know how to reproduce it

Answer (score 0):

Seems like they finally fixed it - can someone else confirm?